# How to get the two decimal places in jolt?

Tags: json, jolt

We have input JSON is like below

**Input JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "price": 120,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "price": 7.88,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "price": 7.8,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "price": 12.849,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1
  }
]
```

From the above input JSON we want to perform some calculation like **price** * **quantity**

**NOTE:** And the number should have up to two decimal places

**Jolt Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "inverseQuantity": "=divide(1,@(1,quantity))",
        "orderTotal": ["=divide(@(1,price),@(1,inverseQuantity))", 0],
        "orderTotalRounded": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,orderTotal),1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "inverseQuantity": "",
        "orderTotal": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

However, we did not receive the expected output from the above Jolt spec. Since we want the decimal up to two places.

**Output JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "price": 120,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalRounded": 120
  },
  {
    "price": 7.88,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalRounded": 7.88
  },
  {
    "price": 7.8,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalRounded": 7.8
  },
  {
    "price": 12.849,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalRounded": 12.85
  },
  {
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalRounded": 0
  }
]
```

**Scenarios**

1. When the price field has 7.8 then it will return 7.8 instead of 7.80
2. When the price field has 0 then it will return 0.0 instead of 0.00
3. When the price field has 1 then it will return 1.0 instead of 1.00

My question is, how can we get the numbers up to two decimal places for all the above cases?

Comment: Yes, we are using Apache NiFi.

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared the solution, below is the jolt spec which I have tried and got the desired output

**Jolt Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "del_inverseQuantity": "=divide(1,@(1,quantity))",
        "del_orderTotal": ["=divideAndRound(2,@(1,price),@(1,del_inverseQuantity))", 0],
        "del_orderTotalString": "=toString(@(1,del_orderTotal))",
        "del_orderTotalSplited": "=split('\\.',@(1,del_orderTotalString))",
        "del_orderTotalPadded": "=rightPad(@(1,del_orderTotalSplited[1]), 2, '0')",
        "orderTotalConcat": "=concat(@(1,del_orderTotalSplited[0]), '.', @(1,del_orderTotalPadded))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "del_*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "price": 120,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalConcat": "120.00"
  },
  {
    "price": 7.88,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalConcat": "7.88"
  },
  {
    "price": 7.8,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalConcat": "7.80"
  },
  {
    "price": 12.849,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalConcat": "12.85"
  },
  {
    "price": 0,
    "quantity": 1,
    "orderTotalConcat": "0.00"
  }
]
```

I want to know if this is the correct way or if I should explore other ways.

Comment: Your current solution, along with a little bit of tweaks, is pretty good. As I searched and witnessed two decimal places for numeric values is not supported for JSON syntax. Therefore, *stringifying* seems to be the only case